# How do I replace punctuation in a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, replace

I would like to *replace* (and not *remove*) all punctuation characters by " " in a string in Python.

Is there something efficient of the following flavour?

```
text = text.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: what's the difference between REMOVE vs REPLACE with nothing??

Comment: no, replace with " " (whitespace)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This answer is for Python 2 and will only work for ASCII strings:

The string module contains two things that will help you: a list of punctuation characters and the "maketrans" function.  Here is how you can use them:

```
import string
replace_punctuation = string.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' '*len(string.punctuation))
text = text.translate(replace_punctuation)
```

Comment: This is the fastest solution, easily beating the regular expression option.

Comment: By far the best answer - fast and complete. :-)

Comment: in python 3 use the following: str.translate()   https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate

Answer (score 21):

Modified solution from [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

```
import string
import re

regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))
out = regex.sub(' ', "This is, fortunately. A Test! string")
# out = 'This is  fortunately  A Test  string'
```

Comment: How would you keep apostrophes, for example in the word don't? I don't want the apostrophes stripped out so that I am left with dont.

Comment: You can remove the apostrophe from string.punctuation (which is in turn just a string containing all punctuation characters).
`string.punctuation.replace("'", "")` leads to ` '!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'`

Answer (score 2):

This workaround works in python 3:

```
import string
ex_str = 'SFDF-OIU .df  !hello.dfasf  sad - - d-f - sd'
#because len(string.punctuation) = 32
table = str.maketrans(string.punctuation,' '*32) 
res = ex_str.translate(table)

# res = 'SFDF OIU  df   hello dfasf  sad     d f   sd'
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a more robust solution which relies on a regex exclusion rather than inclusion through an extensive list of punctuation characters.

```
import re
print(re.sub('[^\w\s]', '', 'This is, fortunately. A Test! string'))
#Output - 'This is fortunately A Test string'
```

The regex catches anything which is not an alpha-numeric or whitespace character

Answer (score 0):

Replace by `''?`.

What's the difference between translating all `;` into '' and remove all `;`?

Here is to remove all `;`:

```
s = 'dsda;;dsd;sad'
table = string.maketrans('','')
string.translate(s, table, ';')
```

And you can do your replacement with translate.

Answer (score 0):

In my specific way, I removed "+" and "&" from the punctuation list:

```
all_punctuations = string.punctuation
selected_punctuations = re.sub(r'(\&|\+)', "", all_punctuations)
print selected_punctuations

str = "he+llo* ithis& place% if you * here @@"
punctuation_regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(selected_punctuations))
punc_free = punctuation_regex.sub("", str)
print punc_free
```

Result: he+llo ithis& place if you here